# Creating a file that will open another file in VS Code when it is double-clicked

Tags: bash, .desktop, bashrc

I want to write a command in `~/.bashrc`that will create a trigger file that will open a different target file in a different folder when I double-click on the trigger file. I want the target file to open in VS Code.

The files might appear in a directory structure like this:

```
parentDir/
  archiveDir/
  yesterdaysDateDir/
  todaysDateDir/
    fileIWantToOpen.js

  index/
    fileIWantToDoubleClick
```

I understand that I can create an executable .desktop file to do this. I have found the [specifications for .desktop files](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html#exec-variables), but I have got lost in all the possible details.

I think that what I want might look something like this...

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=true
Name=fileIWantToDoubleClick
Icon=utilities-terminal
Exec="code '../todaysDate/fileIWantToOpen.js'"
Categories=Application;
```

... but I am out of my depth. Any help in understanding what to do would be appreciated.

Creating a simple symbolic link does not work for me: I want to click on a file in my `index` directory and have it open a specific file in a specific folder, rather than launch a clone with a different name from the `index` directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create bash file

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
code '../todaysDate/fileIWantToOpen.js'
```

make it executable by running this command in the terminal
`chmod +x fileIWantToDoubleClick`

double-click on it to open the file